# Make tier_price behave/replace normal price Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, price, api, import, soap

I'm looking for a way to display my Tier_pricing as a normal price. Because I use SOAP to import prices for different groups.

I've managed to let magento show the tier_prices on list page;

```
<?php  $this->setProduct(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()-      >getStore()->getId())->load($_product->getId()))?> 
<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml()  ?>
```

But, it isn't showing up when the tier_price is higher then the normal price ! How can I work around this? I need it to show up also when tier_price is higher then normal price (basicly my tier_price just needs to replace my normal varien price).

Also, can I make it to show the tier_prices like the normal price (so Incl. & Excl. VAT taxes, is their any way to just get the tier_price into the price-box instead of the price ?). So, I want Magento to think that the tier_price is actually the normal price for a certain customer_group...

I know you can use customer_groups for this, but that can't be used with SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

> But, it isn't showing up when the tier_price is higher then the normal price!

It doesn't make sense to show the tier_price if the normal price is lower. This is not implemented and not intended.

What might help is to implement an observer which listens to some event (I have no idea which at the moment) and replace the price with the `tier_price`. But I'm not sure what the side effects might be.